# Help recognizing components and parts of this radio telescope

Tags: radio, detection

I stumbled upon [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g3LT_b6K0Mc) video, where someone is showcasing a radio telescope that detects wifi frequencies and renders them as picture.

There are three parts, and the one above is just the 3rd part (last part):

- [First part](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o6WHhqDHSQ4)
- [Second part](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VABeN4uv03s)
- [Last part](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g3LT_b6K0Mc) (as posted above)

I watched those multiple times as I was curious about how to reproduce this (for educational purposes of course.)

I managed to understand most of it, and already know how the gears, antenna (coil part) and the dish work, as well as the motors and how to reproduce them.

However, I can't manage to figure out what part/components are used for the wiring between the part that detects the wifi frequencies, the coil on the antenna, the Arduino board and the computer where the rendering of the images is done (though I do understand the part of the [code](https://github.com/FOULAB/Project-COGSWORTH) which does the rendering).

Any help and feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Your question requires us to watch four videos. Can you post some screengrabs of the relevant parts so your question will make sense if the videos are removed? You'll get more interest in your question.

Comment: It's actually three video (i mentioned i posted the last part above first :D) and yes, will get some screenshot, though it'll be a bit hard given the one making those video did *not* show the wiring of what i mentioned in my post (they did show the wiring for the motors briefly though...). @Transistor

Comment: @NordineLotfi:  No need to add "for educational purposes of course."  This purely a receiver. It doesn't even decode wifi data.  It only measures intensity over time.

Comment: I'm aware! I didn't mean anything by it, but i still felt like it was fine saying it. @JRE call it habit if you will :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cogsworth radio "telescope" (it's actually more of a radio camera) uses a software defined radio (SDR) dongle to detect the RF signal.

If you watch the video, you'll see that they used [GNU Radio](https://www.gnuradio.org/) to handle the RF parts of the software.

The GNU Radio Companion as seen in the cogsworth video:

[image]

The GNU Radio site has suggestions for usable SDR hardware if you'd like to build your own.

Cogsworth collects absolute gigabytes worth of SDR data, then spends hours on post-processing to boil the data down to a picture.

---

As an alternative, you could have a look at [the one I built.](https://josepheoff.github.io/posts/3-rfcamera-toc) Mine detects 11GHz radio waves because I used the down converter from a satellite TV dish.  You could use a wifi antenna instead if you like.  Unlike Cogsworth, my project has links to drawings, plans, and software along with written descriptions instead of cool looking but useless videos.

My radio camera takes about 20 minutes to make an image, but when it is done it is done.  It only takes a single analog value for each point.  It collects a few kilobytes of data.

Comment: this is exactly what i needed!